# Does the Contact Key for MobileConnect have to be the Subscriber Key of a Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, import, mobileconnect, sms

I'm creating an Import Definition to Import contact details into MobileConnect's All Contacts' List.

When creating the import definition, it asks for three (3) required fields to be mapped against the Data Extension: Contact Key, Mobile Number, Locale.

My question is, can the Contact Key be mapped to a different field other than the Data Extension's Subscriber Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, you can map this to any field. The Data Extension does not need to be a sendable Data Extension either.